# Display libavcodec log

Tags: debugging, libavcodec, libav

I'm currently playing with libavcodec as a static library, and I would like to get the debug message (printed by the following)

```
av_log(h->avctx, AV_LOG_DEBUG,
                   "NAL_IDR Detected\n");
```

Only the message printed with

```
av_log(h->avctx, AV_LOG_ERROR,
                   "NAL_IDR Detected\n");
```

are currently displayed. Does anyone know how to activate this ? I see a DEBUGLEVEL option in the configure script, but no further description is given.

Regards,

Nicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. set av_log_level = AV_LOG_DEBUG instead of AV_LOG_INFO in libavutils/log.c
2. add "#define DEBUG" in libavutil/log.h